# Initialization of const reference member with deleted copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, uniform-initialization

This code, with a `const A& a` member in `B`, where `A` has a deleted copy constructor, doesn't compile in GCC 4.8.1, but it works OK in clang 3.4:

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};

class B{
public:
    B(const A& a)
        : a{a}
    { }
private:
    const A& a;
};

int main()
{
    A a{};
    B b{a};
}
```

Which one of the compilers is right?

The error in GCC is:

```
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B(const A&)’:
prog.cpp:11:14: error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’
        : a{a}
            ^
prog.cpp:4:5: error: declared here
    A(const A&) = delete;
    ^
```

Ideone: http://ideone.com/x1CVwx

Comment: What's Clang 5.1? The latest version of Clang is 3.5.

Comment: In Mavericks I get this `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`, that's why I put 5.1, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: No wonder it works, compiler is from the future OOOoooOOooooooOO

Comment: The other warning GCC gives might be useful for its thought process: *warning: a temporary bound to 'B::a' only persists until the constructor exits* (`: a{a} {`)

Comment: To fix change to `a(a)`  ; the `{ }` form is requiring a temporary

Comment: NB. You don't need `B` here, simpler example: `A const &z {a};`

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Why should it create an initializer list rather than call the constructor?

Comment: @chris, what constructor? References don't have constructors

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Err, sorry, I was thinking of `A`, but same thing as `int i{5};` then. I see what you're getting at, though. Even with list-initialization, it's still an initializer list.

Comment: Works with gcc 4.9.0, looks like a bug fixed http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ad52924a9c68ebc

Comment: Ahh, *Otherwise, if T is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by T is list-initialized,
and the reference is bound to that temporary. [ Note: As usual, the binding will fail and the program
is ill-formed if the reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. — end note ]*

Comment: @Joachim sorry, I said "initializer list" rather than "list initialization". (The standard does not use the term "uniform initialization"). The `{` ... `}` is called the *initializer list* even if it is not required to construct a `std::initializer_list`

Comment: Duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509603/why-cant-i-initialize-a-reference-in-an-initializer-list-with-uniform-initializ?lq=1) although I don't want to close as Praetorian's answer here is good

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example can be reduced to

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
  A a{};
  A const& ar1(a); 
  A const& ar2{a}; // fails on gcc 4.8
}
```

The initialization of `ar2` fails on gcc-4.8 with the error

```
error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(const A&)’
```

It compiles cleanly on clang3.4 and gcc4.9. This is the result of the resolution to CWG [issue 1288](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1288).

N3337 contains the following language for *list-initialization*:

*§8.5.4/3 [dcl.init.list]*

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>   — `...`
>   — Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by
>   `T` is list-initialized, and the reference is bound to that temporary

This, of course, means that the initialization of `ar2` requires an accessible copy-constructor, hence the error.

---

The language has changed in N3797, where the initialization from an initializer list containing a single element takes precedence over the case quoted above.

> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type `E` and either `T` is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to `E`, the object or reference is initialized from that element; `...`
>   — Otherwise, if `T` is a reference type, a prvalue temporary of the type referenced by `T` is copy-list-initialized or direct-list-initialized, depending on the kind of initialization for the reference, and the reference is bound to that temporary.

So gcc 4.9 and clang 3.4 are implementing the resolution of issue 1288, while gcc 4.8 is following the wording in the C++11 standard.

Comment: The [gcc bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50025) confirming this change was made for gcc4.9

Comment: So, if the code have to support C++11, it should use `ar2(a)`, right? Is the resolution of issue 1288 considered part of C++11 or C++14?

Comment: @smancill Good question. Interestingly, since this situation is not a spot where copy-elision is permitted; if the copy-constructor is not deleted and it has side-effects then this "bug fix" would be a breaking change.

Comment: @smancill Yes, using parentheses instead of braces solves the problem. And I don't really know the answer to your second question. Clearly the resolution was added after the C++11 standard, but you get the fix for free with `-std=c++11` if you upgrade to gcc4.9

Comment: @MattMcNabb Side effects in copy constructors are the real bug :P