# Why doesn't C++11 curly brace initialzation in constructor initialization list work when parens initializaton does?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, initialization, list-initialization

How is {} initialization in a constructor initialization list different from () initialization when initializing reference to abstract types?  Take class Bar below:

```
class AbstractBase
{
public:
    AbstractBase() {}
    virtual ~AbstractBase() = default;

    virtual void ab() = 0;
};

class Foo : public AbstractBase
{
public:
    Foo() {}

    void ab() {}
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(const AbstractBase& base) : myBase{base} {}

private:
    const AbstractBase& myBase;
};


int main()
{
    Foo f{};
    Bar b{f};

}
```

When compiling, I get the error

```
test5.cpp: In constructor ‘Bar::Bar(const AbstractBase&)’:
test5.cpp:22:48: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘AbstractBase’
     Bar(const AbstractBase& base) : myBase{base}
                                                ^
test5.cpp:2:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘AbstractBase’:
 class AbstractBase
       ^
test5.cpp:8:18: note:   virtual void AbstractBase::ab()
     virtual void ab() = 0;
```

Changing the line

```
Bar(const AbstractBase& base) : myBase(base) {}
```

it compiles and runs fine.

Reading through Stroustrup's C++11 book, I was under the impression that {} was the same as () in most all cases, except where there was an ambiguity between constructors that take std::initializer_list<> and other constructors, and cases where using auto as the type, neither of which I'm doing here.

Comment: My rule of thumb: Use `{}` for lists of elements (including zero), and `()` to explicitly call any other constructor.

Comment: This is actually a problem to do with list initialization of references

Comment: Same issue as here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347004/copy-constructor-curly-braces-initialization

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis thanks for that find, I was wondering why my code sample failed to even compile without `S() {}` present!

Comment: @MattMcNabb yeah, got the difference from your answer, didn't think it through deep enough

Comment: Even closer version of the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794598/initialization-of-const-reference-member-with-deleted-copy-constructor/24794857

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer:** This was a bug in the Standard which is fixed in C++14, and g++ 4.9 has the fix (retroactively applied to C++11 mode too). [Defect Report 1288](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288)

---

Here's a simpler example:

```
struct S
{
    int x;
    S() { }     // this causes S to not be an aggregate (otherwise aggregate 
                // initialization is used instead of list initialization)
};

S x = 5;
S const &y { x } ;    

x = 6;
std::cout << y << std::endl;     // output : 5
```

In the text of C++11, the meaning of `S const &y {x};` is not to bind `y` to `x`; in fact the meaning is to create a temporary and bind a reference to that. From C++11 [dcl.init.ref]/3:

> Otherwise, if T is a reference type, **a prvalue temporary** of the type referenced by T is list-initialized, and the reference is bound to that temporary. [Note: As usual, the binding will fail and the program is ill-formed if the reference type is an lvalue reference to a non-const type. —end note ]

This is pretty silly , clearly the intent of this code is to bind `y` directly to `x`. In C++14 the text was changed:

> Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type E and either T is not a reference type or its referenced type is reference-related to E, the object or reference is initialized from that element;

Since a type is reference-related to itself (or one of its base classes), in my sample here and in your actual code, it should actually bind correctly.

---

Your error message comes from the compiler following the C++11 wording and attempting to create a temporary from `base` to bind the reference to; and this fails because `base` is of an abstract type.

Comment: If I remove const from my reference when using {} initialization, I get a different error:
`test5.cpp: In constructor ‘Bar::Bar(AbstractBase&)’:
test5.cpp:22:42: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘AbstractBase&’ from an rvalue of type ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’
     Bar(AbstractBase& base) : myBase{base} {}
                                          ^`

Comment: @oryan_dunn that's attempting to bind a temporary to a non-const reference

Comment: yeah, I realize that now, it's trying to make a temporary of an abstract type.
I guess until C++14 comes along, I'll have to continue to use () on all my constructor initialization lists to remain consistent.

Comment: No, you don't need to wait for C++14, you can just use a newer compiler that implements DR1288.

Comment: I see that GCC 4.9 should fix it, but I'm stuck on 4.8.2 via RHEL 6.5 and devtoolset 2.1.