# Using brace-init to initialize a reference to std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, shared-ptr

I was working on a code recently and I stumbled on something unusual in GCC and Clang. Using brace-init triggers a compilation error in gcc, while a direct initialization such as `&b = a` works. The code below is a very simple example of that behaviour I encountered and I was wondering why GCC doesn't compile the code, since none of shared_ptr takes an initializer_list and `a` is a lvalue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main( )
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> a { nullptr }, &b { a };

    a = std::make_shared<int> ( 1e3 );
    std::cout << ( b ? *b : 0 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Clang 3.4 compiles this but GCC 4.8 doesn't.

Comment: Can't reproduce for gcc 4.9. Probably fixed between versions.

Comment: Might be a defect in list-initialization. Compare N3337 vs N3485. I'll try to find the defect report.

Comment: Here it is: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10509603

Answer (score 3):

The [CWG Defect 1288](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288) as pointed out by @Dyp has been acknowledged and fixed for [GCC 4.9.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50025). A workaround is to use [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) without [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
// Note the parentheses
std::shared_ptr<int> a { nullptr }, &b ( a );
```