# Why does this program compile fine in C++14 but not in a C++11 compiler?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++14, list-initialization

I recently tested the simple following program on an online compiler. See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/Otf3sL). It compiles fine & gives the expected output but when I tested it on Dev C++ IDE it fails during the compilation.

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
class Test
{
    int s=9;
    public:
    int get_s()
    {
        return s;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Test s;
    Test& t{s};      // error in C++11 but not in C++14 why???
    std::cout<<t.get_s();
}
```

It gives me following error:

```
[Error] invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Test&' from an rvalue of type '<brace-enclosed initializer list>'
```

I also tried it on code blocks 13.12 IDE & it gives me the same error as Dev C++ gives.

Is this a new C++14 feature? Why is it not working in a C++11 compiler?

Comment: [It is working](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fbf7065dd424257). Perhaps something missing in a C++11-incomplete compiler?

Comment: @MarcoA. yes, it is working in C++14 compiler but not working in C++11 compiler. Have you tried this program in C++0x compiler?

Comment: @meet Did you notice that the link uses `-std=c++11`, not `-std=c++14`?

Comment: @hvd: oh sorry just noticed that after you said. But it fails in compilation on my compiler.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50025. Is mingw/gcc the underlying compiler? If so: which version?

Comment: it works on gcc 4.9.2 with c++11. Your compiler most likely doesn't implement c++11 fully

Comment: @MarcoA. That's not just related, that's exactly it. A post-C++11 DR changed the rule, and C++11 compilers should implement the changed rule, but this was done in GCC 4.9. GCC 4.8 and earlier implement the original C++11 rule. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509603/why-cant-i-initialize-a-reference-in-an-initializer-list-with-uniform-initializ

Comment: When reporting compilation problems you should mention the version number of the compiler, not the version of "code blocks".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works on C++14 and also [works on C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fbf7065dd424257). You're very likely using an out-of-date compiler.

There's a fixed bug (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50025) for your exact issue (cfr. DR 1288)

> C++0x initialization syntax doesn't work for class members of reference type

Quoting from [Jonathan Wakely](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50025#c24)

> The original C++11 rules required a temporary to be created there and the reference member binds to that temporary.

Sources: [Defect Report 1288](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288)

Answer (score 3):

It works on both `c++11` and `c++14` on all these compilers:

```
gcc 4.9.2
gcc 5.1.0
clang 3.5.0
```

Most likely you are using an old version of gcc  or another compiler that didn't implement yet this c++11 feature.

c++11 was implemented on stages by compilers. Each version added/improved/fix some c++11 features.