# Why doesn't this work? (brace-initialization of references)

Tags: c++, reference, list-initialization

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    struct A
    {
        unsigned char l;
        std::array<char, 12> c;
    };

    const A a = {1, "t"}; // OK
    const A& ar = {1, "t"}; // error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const main()::A&' from expression of type '<brace-enclosed initializer list>'
}
```

(gcc 8.2, -std=c++17)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509603/why-cant-i-initialize-a-reference-in-an-initializer-list-with-uniform-initializ) talks about a GCC bug, but it's old (7 years ago).

Note that I don't care about lifetime extension, I'm actually passing the temporary directly into a function for use rather than store it but I tried making the example clean.

---

**Edit:**

- I cannot make the example smaller. In particular, it has to do with the `array<char>`.
- Adding more braces around "t" and still fails.
- Something that works is exploding the string literal into characters:

  ```
  const A& ar = {1, {'a', 'b'}}; // works
  ```

Comment: I think the code is correct and it's a gcc bug (although not related to the other question you linked)

Comment: Does indeed work on clang. https://wandbox.org/permlink/7oAmpGhjS4o7u7Oa

Comment: as an aside, does adding an explicit nameless temporary yields the exact same result? Like so: `const A& art = A{1, "ab"};`  This would sort it for what I'm doing

Comment: I'm not sure it's even valid to count on a simpler initialization like `std::array<char, 12> c{"hello"};`.  Although a raw array member of type `T[N]` is the most likely implementation, the Standard only says that a `std::array<T,N>` is an aggregate which can be list-initialized from an initializer list with up to `N` elements.  So an implementation like `template <class T, size_t N> struct array { T __elem; array<T, N-1> __rest; };` would also be compliant.

Comment: @aschepler in aggregate initialization it says that a string literal can be used to initialize a char array (and std::array is specified as being an aggregate containing an array)

Comment: @haelix that's what the code means anyway, so if the compiler accepts it then go for it

Comment: Oops, my recursive definition wouldn't support the requirement of being a contiguous container, or the `data()` member (unless maybe the implementation knows indexing the elements as array elements will work in practice). But @M.M I don't see any requirement that `std::array` contains an array element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that the initializer `{1, "t"}` is using *brace elision* to initialize the sub-aggregate `A.c` which means that the literal `"t"` is taken to directly initialize the internal array that `std::array` holds. In this case, this array would look like `char data[12]`.

This reduces to say that *we are initializing a reference to `const A` with a brace-list containing an element that initializes a member array*.

This will be somewhat equivalent to:

```
struct S {
    char const data[2];
};
S const& s = {"t"}; // fail for gcc
```

GCC has already a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67259) on that.

You've already provided a workaround in the comment section. Just initialize the reference as:

```
const A& ar = A{1, "t"}
```